# Get the time my page started running angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, time, cgi

I am making an app displaying the current system time but I want to get the time my page started running so I can calculate and display the time that my page is up and running. I am using angularjs and currently has no idea on how can I get this. I have my code on getting the current system time like this

```
 Current time is:
      <span my-current-time="format1"></span>
      <span my-current-time="format"></span> :
      <span my-current-time="format3"></span> :
      <span my-current-time="format4"></span> 
      <span my-current-time="format5"></span>
```

with this script

```
 $scope.format1 = 'M/d/yy  ';
      $scope.format = 'h';
      $scope.format3 = 'mm';
      $scope.format4 = 'ss';
      $scope.format5 = 'a';
      $scope.format2 = 'Z ';
```

and a directive like this

```
.directive("myCurrentTime", function(dateFilter) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var format;
                scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
                  format = value;
                  updateTime();

                });
              function updateTime() {
                var dt = dateFilter(new Date(), format );
                         element.text(dt);
                      }

                      function updateLater() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                          updateTime(); // update DOM
                          updateLater(); // schedule another update
                        }, 1000);
                      }

                      updateLater();
                    }
                  });
```

I just want to display the total hours my page is currently running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first save the page load value... $scope.pageLoad = new Date()

and then use a filter to display that value

```
    <p>running since : {{pageLoan | timespan}}</p>
```

and define timespan filter

```
  angular.filter(timespan, function(time){
         var now = new Date();
         return (now - time) / 1000;
   });
```

Comment: Thanks @entre but if it's not too much to ask can you show me an example?

Comment: where will i put the filter? with the controller or with the directive?

Comment: They are independent, put them on module. Please google about them

Comment: sorry if get too much of your time but can you please take a look on my plunker? I think it's messed up and I don't know why. http://plnkr.co/edit/4XRjszIATgvUVrofgRFI?p=preview @entre